# Laravel 8 PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor как удалить пеенос строки

Tags: laravel, phpword

Дано: Laravel  8
PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor
Записи в файле:

```html
Тел.: ${phone}
${test5}
E-mail: ${email}
```

Код:

```html
$templateProcessor->setValue('test5', '');
```

Задача, если нет значения, то удалять строку.
Всем спасибо!

Comment: Как мысль. Написть в общей строке с предыдущей или следующей строкой. И когда надо вставить `test5` вставлять ещё и перенос строки.

Comment: Добрый день, да, как вариант, но это "костылик", хотелось бы базовое решение.

Comment: Кому интересно, то перенос строки в word, через эту библиотеку: <w:br/>